# Are there any quests that I can miss?

Tags: grim-dawn

Are there any time-based quests that I will not be able to complete once I pass a certain Act of the game? Can I always go back and complete quests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most quests you can simply go back if you've missed it. The only exception to this is a questline belonging to a faction that can either be friendly or hostile.

This applies for the following factions:

**Vanilla**

- Kymon's Chosen
- Orther of Death's Vigil
- The Outcast

**Ashes of Malmouth**

- Barrowholm

If you chose to become enemies with one of the factions mentioned above you will not be able to play their questline **in the current playthrough**. 
This means you can still become allied with them in a later playthrough though.